# How to distinguish between two Different Named Entities of same name?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have few articles, in which I am taking out name using NER Model (Named Entity Recognition). Since NER is classifying into four categories ( PERSON, LOCATION, ORGANISATION, MISCELLANEOUS ). Now I having two people of same name. How will I go about distinguishing between them? 
Kindly direct me towards some research available on this problem, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task you need is called [Entity Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking), it is a harder problem than Named Entity Recognition.

A good way to start research on this problem is the [ACL anthology](https://aclanthology.coli.uni-saarland.de/catalog?utf8=%E2%9C%93&utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_field=all_fields&q=named+entity+linking&range%5Bpublish_date%5D%5Bbegin%5D=2015&range%5Bpublish_date%5D%5Bend%5D=2017&range%5Bpublish_date%5D%5Bbegin%5D=2016&range%5Bpublish_date%5D%5Bend%5D=2017&commit=Limit).